# How to Redux a Reactjs crime map application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a demo react application - and its important to add redux to this. Please review the following code and help me invoke the redux appropriately.

I would like to understand how to add sister components later on to such an application to share this communication channel - if it be create a master/slave relationship between charts/components as such.

// index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
//import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
//import { createStore } from 'redux'

import MapChart from './modules/mapChart/MapChart'
import './index.css'

// this is how you'll get your icon links
// instead of a switch with loads of repetitive bytes
const iconMap = {
  'anti-social-behaviour':  'green-dot',
  'burglary':               'red-dot',
  'criminal-damage-arson':  'yellow-dot',
  'drugs':                  'purple-dot',
  'other-theft':            'pink-dot',
  'shoplifting':            'blue-dot',
  'vehicle-crime':          'orange-dot',
  'other-crime':            'ltblue-dot'
}

// this is a class because it needs state
class CrimeMap extends Component {
  // to do this you have to make sure you have
  // the transform-class-properties feature in babel
  // otherwise just set your initial state in a constructor
  // constructor(props) {
  //   super(props)
  //   this.state = { markers: [] }
  // }
  state = {
    markers: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // use fetch instead of jQuery
    // jQuery is a big lib to be loading for some fetching
    fetch(this.props.source)
      .then( response => response.json() )
      .then(
        json => this.setState({
          markers: this.mapLayerData(json)
        }),
        err => { 
          // handle errors 
        }
      )
  }

  // store only the data you want to pass as props to each Marker
  // instead of mapping it directly in MapChart every time it renders
  mapLayerData(markers) {
    // use a standard map function instead of $.each
    // destructuring saves time and repetition
    return markers.map(({ category, location }) => ({
      // use a template string and a simple map of icon names to get your icon uri
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/'+ iconMap[category] +'.png',
      label: category,
      name: category,
      position: {
        lat: location.latitude,
        lng: location.longitude
      }
    }))
  }

  render() {
    // there's only one layer, so render it directly
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <MapChart markers={this.state.markers} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

//https://data.police.uk/docs/method/crime-street/
render(
    <CrimeMap source="https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?poly=52.268,0.543:52.794,0.238:52.130,0.478&date=2017-01" />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

// MapChart.js

```
import React from 'react'
// only load what you're actually using
import { Map, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps-react'
import './MapChart.css'

// this is a stateless component, it doesn't need state or event handlers
const MapContainer = ({ google, markers }) => (
  <Map 
    google={google} 
    initialCenter={{
      lat: 52.268,
      lng: 0.543
    }}
    zoom={9}
  >
    {
      markers.map((marker, i) =>
        // since you've mapped your data to just the props you need
        // you can just spread it into the component

        <Marker
            key={i}
            icon={marker.icon}
            title={marker.label}
            name={marker.name}
            position={{lat: marker.position.lat, lng: marker.position.lng}} />

      )
    }
  </Map>
)

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: 'xxxxx'
})(MapContainer)
```

// MapChart.css

```
 /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
   * element that contains the map. */
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

/////////////

this is as far as I have got with adding redux -- but I am getting an error

Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. I was basing this of this example - but I don't understand how to add/define this thunk? What it is?

http://jsfiddle.net/cdagli/b2uq8704/6/

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import {Provider, connect} from 'react-redux'
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux' 
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import MapChart from './modules/mapChart/MapChart'
import './index.css'

function fetchPostsRequest(){
  return {
    type: "FETCH_REQUEST"
  }
}

function fetchPostsSuccess(payload) {
  return {
    type: "FETCH_SUCCESS",
    payload
  }
}

function fetchPostsError() {
  return {
    type: "FETCH_ERROR"
  }
}

const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_REQUEST":
      return state;
    case "FETCH_SUCCESS": 
      return {...state, posts: action.payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
} 

function fetchPostsWithRedux() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchPostsRequest());
    return fetchPosts().then(([response, json]) =>{
      if(response.status === 200){
        dispatch(fetchPostsSuccess(json))
      }
      else{
        dispatch(fetchPostsError())
      }
    })
  }
}

function fetchPosts() {
  const URL = 'https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?poly=52.268,0.543:52.794,0.238:52.130,0.478&date=2017-01';
  return fetch(URL, { method: 'GET'})
     .then( response => Promise.all([response, response.json()]));
}



// this is how you'll get your icon links
// instead of a switch with loads of repetitive bytes
const iconMap = {
  'anti-social-behaviour':  'green-dot',
  'burglary':               'red-dot',
  'criminal-damage-arson':  'yellow-dot',
  'drugs':                  'purple-dot',
  'other-theft':            'pink-dot',
  'shoplifting':            'blue-dot',
  'vehicle-crime':          'orange-dot',
  'other-crime':            'ltblue-dot'
}

// this is a class because it needs state
class CrimeMap extends Component {
  // to do this you have to make sure you have
  // the transform-class-properties feature in babel
  // otherwise just set your initial state in a constructor
  // constructor(props) {
  //   super(props)
  //   this.state = { markers: [] }
  // }
  state = {
    markers: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('prop ', this.props)
    // use fetch instead of jQuery
    // jQuery is a big lib to be loading for some fetching
    fetch(this.props.source)
      .then( response => response.json() )
      .then(
        json => this.setState({
          markers: this.mapLayerData(json)
        }),
        err => { 
          // handle errors 
        }
      )
  }

  // store only the data you want to pass as props to each Marker
  // instead of mapping it directly in MapChart every time it renders
  mapLayerData(markers) {
    // use a standard map function instead of $.each
    // destructuring saves time and repetition
    return markers.map(({ category, location }) => ({
      // use a template string and a simple map of icon names to get your icon uri
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/'+ iconMap[category] +'.png',
      label: category,
      name: category,
      position: {
        lat: location.latitude,
        lng: location.longitude
      }
    }))
  }

  render() {
    // there's only one layer, so render it directly
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <MapChart markers={this.state.markers} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}



function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    posts: state.posts
  }
}


let Container = connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchPostsWithRedux})(CrimeMap);

const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);


//https://data.police.uk/docs/method/crime-street/
render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Container/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: posting the redux implementation that you have tried (if not please start from [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/index.html)) will attract more helps.

Comment: Its either one of these - implemented or not - kind of situations. I'd rather see how its done cleanly and why - then just shove up anything

Comment: there are [examples](https://github.com/reactjs/redux#examples) that you can refer to see how its done cleanly, and there are many famous boilerplates. Redux is a [concept](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/CoreConcepts.html) and a set of APIs that you can use to manage the application state. You can choose any implementation which is appealing for you and that suits your needs.

Comment: @TheOldCountry So you're asking someone to write it all for you? There's never going to be an example so specific it does everything you want.

Comment: I am asking someone who KNOWS to rewrite the demo - properly.

Comment: Put it on github and share the link with me

Comment: _I've added the redux - but my data is not plotting, not sure why - and I am not sure where to start with the redux.

Comment: This should be closed. It's silly that a bounty can prevent a question from being closed...

Comment: Why should it be closed - adding redux to an application - properly - but simply - and discussing why and how its done this way.

Comment: Because "rewrite my application" is far too broad - your question should be scoped to a specific problem that you're encountering.

Comment: It is specific - using this application demo - with a json call - how do you properly include/use redux - which would form the backbone for other sister component handling and general data channels.

Comment: The equally specific answer is "read one of the dozens of tutorials on getting started with Redux".

Comment: I see a lot of people here who appear to be experts, but no answers.

Comment: this is what I got going on now -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/98/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the flow of the code you have shared
1. When the component mounts, it calls a function
2. this function "fetchPostsWithRedux" then dispatches actions also, it send an api call to server to fetch data
3. when the data is received component re-renders with updated data as prop.

Now if you want to use mapLayerData function to give the data to the component, without using the "old fetch method", you can do it as mentioned below

add a function naming componentWillReceiveProps

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){

    this.setState({markers: this.mapLayerData(nextProps.posts)});

}
```

Once you call this, state of the component will now have the data, that we have received from the api call

Hope the  above solution has given some clarity about it.

Comment: I need your assistance on a register form -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45942891/reactjs-redux-storing-data-from-a-form-submission